# How do I move modify the origin and orientation of a blueprint in Space Engineers?

Tags: space-engineers

I'm trying to use a projector to duplicate a ship, but the position and angle of the blueprint aren't what I want.

I know you can use the projector to position the blueprint, but I'd like to reduce the need for this. Rotating the ship and rotating the character before saving the blueprint don't seem to help. What can I do to change the initial orientation of a projection relative to the projector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1
Use the Info screen to turn on pivot point visibility.

Step 2
Create a new ship of the appropriate class and reshape it until you have a block in the desired position related to the pivot point of the new ship.

Step 3
Use the blueprint/clipboard to create the ship you are trying to change.  Position it so it is attached to the desired pivot block from the "ship" in step 2.

Step 4
Remove the extra blocks from the ship in step 2

Step 5 
Update your blueprint to have the new pivot point.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are asking about pivot points, which are explained near the end of this video at the 7:34 mark.

Comment: Please provide all of the details needed to answer the question in your own words within the answer.  If that video is ever taken down, we still want all of the necessary information here.